# Python performing calculation in a list

Tags: python, list

I have this list`[9,4,5]` I want to multiply each element by 2 then I sum the result I will get
`9*2=18,4*2=8,5*2=10` then I sum `18+8+10=36`

Can you guys help me to write this please

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: `sum(x * 2 for x in the_list)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to multiply each element by 2; just multiply the whole sum by 2 afterwards.

```py
>>> data = [9, 4, 5]
>>> 2 * sum(data)
36
```

Comment: Even works for some cases where the original plan doesn't, for example `data = [1e308, -1e308]`.

Comment: If OP wants only to multiply by 2 then but-wise will be an alternative solution.  `sum(data)  << 1` . Not saying current solution is bad (actually the best solution posted here).

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` and a list-comprehension

```
sum([x*2 for x in your_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum and a generator expression:

```
>>> data = [9,4,5]
>>> sum(n*2 for n in data)
36
```